# Adding a user to MySQL using C/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I have to write a C/C++ program to add a user to MySQL using C/C++ for a project. The user would only be allowed to INSERT in a given database.

How can I do this?? Please help.

Comment: You could improve this post by telling us about what you've tried so far, what you suspect to be the right answer, and what specifically you don't know. Do you not know how to open a connection to a DB, or is it that you don't know how to Insert into the users table? Or maybe you don't know how to write and compile a C++ program. From your questio we just can't tell.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use MySql C++ [connector.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/)

Answer (score 3):

Your queries to insert the user would be:

```
CREATE 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT INSERT ON database.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

You will need to use a C++ [connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) to connect to the mysql server and then run these queries.

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
MYSQL* mysql;

/* Establish a connection to MySQL etc */

mysql_query(mysql, "CREATE 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'");
mysql_query(mysql, "GRANT INSERT ON database.* TO 'username'@'localhost'");
```

This is a very simple example, you will need to add error checking etc.

Related links:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html